# Why am I getting the error message about each list item should get a unique key when using the react-bootstrap with Nextjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-bootstrap

Here is the current setup of the file right now below. You will see that my file does indeed have a key to each child component but its still flagging it and I think its more internal issues that I am not sure that I can fix.

```js
export default function SecondaryNav(props:NavItems) {

    const router = useRouter();
    let [filteredSubNavItems, setFilteredSubNavItems] = useState<{}[]>([])



/* Filtering the props.navigation array and setting the filteredSubNavItems state to the filtered
array. */
    useEffect(() => {
         props.navigation.filter((item) => {
            if(item.link == router.route) {
                setFilteredSubNavItems(item.subLinks);
            }
        })
    })


    return (
        <>
            <Navbar className={[styles.SecondaryNav].join(' ')}>
                    <div className={['container', styles.secondaryNavContainer].join(' ')}>
                                {
                                    filteredSubNavItems.map((navItem, index) => {
                                        return (
                                            <>
                                            {
                                                !navItem.subLinksExist ?
                                                    <Nav.Link key={navItem.name} href={navItem.link}>{navItem.name}</Nav.Link>
                                                 :
                                                    <NavDropdown key={navItem.name} title={navItem.name} id={navItem.name}>
                                                        {
                                                            navItem.sublinks.map((item) => {
                                                                return (
                                                                    <NavDropdown.Item key={item.label}>{item.label}</NavDropdown.Item>
                                                                )
                                                            })
                                                        }
                                                    </NavDropdown>
                                            }
                                        </>
                                        )
                                    })
                                }
                    </div>
            </Navbar>
        </>
    )
}
```

And below is the file that I am pulling the data.

```js
export const menuItems = [
    {
        primaryLink: 'Home',
        link: '/',
        subLinks: [
            {
                name: 'tutorial',
                subLinksExist: false,
                link: '/Home/Tutorial'
            },
            {
                name: 'contact',
                subLinksExist: false,
                link: '/Home/Contact'
            },
            {
                name: 'about',
                subLinksExist: false,
                link: '/Home/About'
            },
            {
                name: 'FAQ',
                subLinksExist: false,
                link: '/Home/Faq'
            },
            {
                name: 'version',
                subLinksExist: false,
                link: '/Home/Version'
            },
            {
                name: 'health check',
                subLinksExist: false,
                link: '/Home/Healthcheck'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        primaryLink: 'Configuration',
        link: '/Configuration',
        subLinks: [
            {
                name: 'merchants',
                link: 'merchants',
                subLinksExist: true,
                ariaControls: false,
                ariaExpanded: false,
                sublinks: [
                    {
                        label: 'Billing Groups',
                        key: 'billing groups',
                        link: 'Configuration/Merchants/BillingGroup'
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Billing Group Chain',
                        key: 'billing group chain',
                        link: 'Configuration/Merchants/BillingGroupChain'
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Payment Channels',
                        key: 'payment channels',
                        link: 'Configuration/Merchants/PaymentChannels'
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Relationship Managers',
                        key: 'relationship managers',
                        link: 'Configuration/Merchants/RelationshipManagers'
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Fee Templates',
                        key: 'fee templates',
                        link: 'Configuration/Merchants/FeeTemplates'
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Billing Group Disbursement Hold',
                        key: 'billing group disbursement hold',
                        link: 'Configuration/Merchants/BillingGroupDisbursementHold'
                    },
                ]
            },
            {
                name: 'partners',
                subLinksExist: false,
                link: 'Configuration/Partners'
            },
            {
                name: 'ODFIs',
                link: '/odfis',
                subLinksExist: true,
                ariaControls: false,
                ariaExpanded: false,
                sublinks: [
                    {
                        label: 'Bank Expenses',
                        key: 'bank expenses',
                        link: 'Configuration/ODFIs/BankExpenses'
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Expense Batches',
                        key: 'expense batches',
                        link: 'Configuration/ODFIs/ExpenseBatches'
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Routing Numbers',
                        key: 'routing numbers',
                        link: 'Configuration/ODFIs/RoutingNumbers'
                    },
                ]
            },
            {
                name: 'business units',
                link: '/businessunits',
                subLinksExist: true,
                ariaControls: false,
                ariaExpanded: false,
                sublinks: [
                    {
                        label: 'Support Contacts',
                        key: 'support contacts',
                        link: 'Configuration/BusinessUnits/SupportContacts'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                name: 'profile',
                link: '/profile',
                subLinksExist: true,
                ariaControls: false,
                ariaExpanded: false,
                sublinks: [
                    {
                        label: 'API Profiles',
                        key: 'api profiles',
                        link: 'Configuration/Profile/APIProfiles'
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Heartland Users',
                        key: 'heartland users',
                        link: 'Configuration/Profile/HeartlandUsers'
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'External Users',
                        key: 'external users',
                        link: 'Configuration/Profile/ExternalUsers'
                    },
                ]
            },
            {
                name: 'system',
                subLinksExist: false,
                link: 'Configuration/System'
            }
        ]
    },
     {
        primaryLink: 'Support',
        link: '/Support',
        subLinks: [
            {
                name: 'automation',
                link: '/automation',
                subLinksExist: true,
                sublinks: [
                    {
                        label: 'Alerts',
                        link: '/Support/Automation/Alerts'
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Subscriptions',
                        link: '/Support/Automation/Subscriptions'
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Jobs',
                        link: '/Support/Automation/Jobs'
                    },
                ]
            },
            {
                name: 'consumers',
                link: '/Consumers',
                subLinksExist: true,
                sublinks: [
                    {
                        label: 'Blacklist',
                        link: '/Support/Consumers/Blacklist'
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Whitelist',
                        link: '/Support/Consumers/Whitelist'
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Provisional Whitelist',
                        link: '/Support/Consumers/ProvisionalWhitelist'
                    },
                ]
            },
            {
                name: 'invoices',
                link: '/Invoices',
                subLinksExist: true,
                sublinks: [
                    {
                        label: 'Billing Group',
                        link: '/Support/Invoices/BillingGroup'
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Partner',
                        link: '/Support/Invoices/Partner'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                name: 'logging',
                link: '/Logging',
                subLinksExist: true,
                sublinks: [
                    {
                        label: 'Failed Api Calls',
                        link: '/Support/Logging/FailedApiCalls'
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Logs',
                        link: '/Support/Logging/Logs'
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Emails',
                        link: '/Support/Logging/Emails'
                    },
                ]
            },
            {
                name: 'ACH files',
                link: '/AchFiles',
                subLinksExist: true,
                sublinks: [
                    {
                        label: 'ACH Entry Finder',
                        link: '/Support/AchFiles/AchEntryFinder'
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'ACH Rejects',
                        link: '/Support/AchFiles/AchRejects'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                name: 'returns',
                link: '/Returns',
                subLinksExist: true,
                sublinks: [
                    {
                        label: 'Return Files',
                        link: '/Support/Returns/ReturnFiles'
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Return Details',
                        link: '/Support/Returns/ReturnDetails'
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Exceptions',
                        link: '/Support/Returns/Exceptions'
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Reinitiations',
                        link: '/Support/Returns/Reinitiations'
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Notices Of Change',
                        link: '/Support/Returns/NoticeOfChange'
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Return Reconciliations',
                        link: '/Support/Returns/ReturnReconciliations'
                    },
                ]
            },
            {
                name: 'bulwark',
                link: '/Bulwark',
                subLinksExist: true,
                sublinks: [
                    {
                        label: 'Risk Rule Configuration',
                        link: '/Support/Bulwark/RiskRuleConfiguration'
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Risk Rule Enforcement',
                        link: '/Support/Bulwark/RiskRuleEnforcement'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
     },
    {
        primaryLink: 'Terminal',
        link: '/Terminal',
        subLinks: [
            {
                name: 'virtual terminal',
                subLinksExist: false,
                link: '/VirtualTerminal'
            },
            {
                name: 'history log',
                subLinksExist: false,
                link: '/HistoryLog'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        primaryLink: 'Sagacity',
        link: '/Sagacity',
        subLinks: [
            {
                name: 'management',
                link: '/Management',
                subLinksExist: true,
                sublinks: [
                    {
                        label: 'Business Units',
                        link: '/Sagacity/Management/BusinessUnits'
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Merchants',
                        link: '/Sagacity/Management/Merchants'
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Users',
                        link: '/Sagacity/Management/Users'
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Global',
                        link: '/Sagacity/Management/Global'
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'GIACT Invoices',
                        link: '/Sagacity/Management/GIACTInvoices'
                    },
                ]
            },
            {
                name: 'history',
                link: '/History',
                subLinksExist: true,
                sublinks: [
                    {
                        label: 'Bank Accounts',
                        link: '/Sagacity/History/BankAccounts'
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Consumers',
                        link: '/Sagacity/History/Consumers'
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Verification Requests',
                        link: '/Sagacity/History/VerificationRequests'
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Authentication Requests',
                        link: '/Sagacity/History/AuthenticationRequests'
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Statics',
                        link: '/Sagacity/History/Statics'
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Failed API Calls',
                        link: '/Sagacity/History/FailedApiCalls'
                    },
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

It is primarily flagging just the dropdown menus only. If you remove the dropdown components I dont get the error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the output of `filteredSubNavItems.map()` is wrapped in a `<></>` fragment tag, and the error could be that this does not have an unique key.

Perhaps try give the fragment tag a key such as:

```
// '<></>' syntax may not work when keyed, might also need to import 'React'

filteredSubNavItems.map((navItem, index) => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment key={navItem.name}>
      {!navItem.subLinksExist ? (
        <Nav.Link key={navItem.name} href={navItem.link}>
          {navItem.name}
        </Nav.Link>
      ) : (
        <NavDropdown key={navItem.name} title={navItem.name} id={navItem.name}>
          {navItem.sublinks.map((item) => {
            return (
              <NavDropdown.Item key={item.label}>{item.label}</NavDropdown.Item>
            );
          })}
        </NavDropdown>
      )}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
});
```

Or perhaps not to wrap the `return` in a `<></>`, instead do different `return` with condition:

```
filteredSubNavItems.map((navItem, index) => {
  if (!navItem.subLinksExist)
    return (
      <Nav.Link key={navItem.name} href={navItem.link}>
        {navItem.name}
      </Nav.Link>
    );
  return (
    <NavDropdown key={navItem.name} title={navItem.name} id={navItem.name}>
      {navItem.sublinks.map((item) => {
        return (
          <NavDropdown.Item key={item.label}>{item.label}</NavDropdown.Item>
        );
      })}
    </NavDropdown>
  );
});
```

Comment: You can even keep the ternary operator in the return and just remove the fragment wrapper since it only wraps one element anyway. However I prefer the conditional return approach you've posted here.